# Are the two definitions of cap product equivalent? Are they geometrically related? (Definition using tensor product vs. using cartesian product)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, tensor-products, intuition

I'm self-studying AT using Munkres's book *Elements of Algebraic Topology*. So far, I'm going through the two important operations: cup product and cap product (This is my first time of learning it). I think they must be related somehow.

For cup product, I can see the intuition behind the definition by considering the case of differentiable manifold. Suppose $M$ is a smooth $n$-manifold, then the cup product on its cohomology group is given by
$$\smile:\Omega^k(M)\times\Omega^l(M)\to\Omega^{k+l}(M),\text{ }([\omega^k],[\omega^l])\mapsto[\omega^k\wedge\omega^l]$$
which is intuitively understandable as it can be understood as a manipulation of vectors, even though I'm not really sure if my observation is valid.

---

For the same purpose, I tried to understand Munkres's definition of cap product, but it really confuses me.

> **Munkres's definition:**

> However, in Munkres's book, he defines cap product as follows: Suppose $X$ is a topological space, then
> $$\frown:S^p(X;R)\otimes S_{p+q}(X;R)\to S_q(X;R);$$
> Suppose $T:\Delta_{p+q}\to X$ is a singular simplex in $X$, and $\alpha\in R$, then it can be defined explicitly using the formula
> $$c^p\frown(T\otimes\alpha)=T|_{v_0,\ldots,v_q}\otimes\alpha\langle c^p,T|_{v_q,\ldots,v_{p+q}}\text{ 
>  }\rangle$$
> where $\langle a,b\rangle$ notation refers to the evaluation of $a$ on $b$, i.e, the value of cochain $a$ on chain $b$.

**Q:Why is it defined using tensor product? (Probably this is a stupid question, but I think I missed something important)**

---

Motivated by the question above, I thought about my way of defining it with the reference of the meaning of cup product.

> **The definition I'm thinking about:**

> Because the cup product sends two cochains to another cochain with dimension equal to the sum of the previous two, so using the same idea, we can define cap product accordingly.

> Suppose $X$ is a topological space, then I think Cartesian product is already sufficient.
> $$\frown:S^p(X;R)\times S_{p+q}(X;R)\to S_q(X;R)$$
> which can be defined by
> $$c^p\frown (T:\Delta_{p+q}\to X)=\langle c^p,T|_{v_0,\ldots,v_p}\text{ } \rangle T|_{v_p,\ldots,v_{p+q}}$$
> This says that the cap product of the two things is the restriction of $T$ onto the $q$-face with the coefficient of the evaluation multiplied before it, which is clearly in $S_q(X;R)$

**Q: Is this valid also?** (I think that it's valid) **Also, I just couldn't understand what's the role of tensor product in Munkres's definition. Is there a geometric intuition for him to use tensor product to define cap product? (since tensor product cannot be regarded as product directly)** If they're both valid, how can we show that they're equivalent? (My thought is to use the isomorphism of tensor product, but it doesn't give us equality, so I'm a bit confused)

**Q: I previewed the application of cap product... Although it can be understood as an "analogue?!" to cup product, I'm still curious about how to visualize it using the same idea in de-Rham cohomology as I did with the cup product...**

Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: Q1. Yes, it's valid. The connection is that the function you defined is *bilinear*, and there's a correspondence between bilinear maps $A\times B\to C$ and linear maps $A\otimes B\to C$.

Comment: @Berci Oh! Thank you very much! I missed that the aim for defining tensor product is to convert the investigation of bilinear map to the study of homomorphism from $A\otimes B\overset{f}{\to} C$. Now it makes perfect sense for two definitions to be equivalent. Thank you!

Comment: @Berci I think maybe *cup* product can be defined also using tensor product as it admits bilinearity as well.

Comment: Yes, it seems so.